# PHP Session variable is empty after redirecting to another page

Tags: php, session, backend

I'm creating a `PHP` session, username and all, but when I redirect with header(`foo.php`), the `$_SESSION` variable appears empty, even though before redirecting it appears properly filled when checking with var_dump.

First I create the session:

```
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
   echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];

   header('location:login-success.php');
   exit();
```

On the next page I start session on top of the page, no HTML above, no nothing:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo "nope";
    }
?>
```

The output is always "nope". I've tried on my localhost and on a remote host, several browsers, cookies are enabled. $_SESSION appears empty when checking with var_dump now.

Comment: Upon creating the session, have you started it? Are you sure you're not accidentally destroying it?

Comment: Did you do a `session_start()` in the script that is loading the data into the session

Comment: `session_start();` needed on each page on top where you are going to deal with `SESSION` in any way.So add it in your first page

Comment: @AlivetoDie that is exactly what I was missing. I feel so dumb because it took me hours and I couldn't figure out on my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_start();` needed on each page on top where you are going to deal with `SESSION` in any way (create,update,delete).

So add it in your first page  like below:-

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['start'] = time();
  $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
  echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];

  header('location:login-success.php');
  exit();
```

Comment: on wordpress it doesn't work